# Does the emulator do a full reset on startup

Tags: windows-phone-8, emulation

When the emulator is closed and reopened in Visual Studio,
does it do a full reset?

I am new to programming for Windows Phone and trying to make a simple program
to save a text file.

Will a saved file be deleted everytime I do a new startup of the emulator?

Comment: There is a work around if you absolutely need to persist data in the emulator http://sviluppomobile.blogspot.com.au/2013/01/saving-windows-phone-8-emulator-state.html

Personally, I prefer to have a fresh emulator every start.

Comment: That might be usefull in future projects, but as for now, I share your preferences :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [MSDN says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402563%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_Featuresandlimitationsoftheemulator):

> Data in isolated storage persists while the emulator is running, but is lost once the emulator closes. For more info about isolated storage, see Quickstart: Working with files and folders in Windows Phone 8.

Comment: @TomCB You are welcome. When somebody answers your question and it solved your problem, don't forget to mark it as a solution (green tick besides). Good luck with coding and documentation reading ;)